# Having a difficulty with the javascript code in th for part with button color change

Tags: javascript, loops, class, button, undefined

My original code but the letter 'i' received a message as undefined.
original code.

```
function buttonRed {

  for (let i=0; i < all_buttons.length; i++)  {
   all_buttons[i].classList.remove(all_buttons[i].classList[1];
   all_buttons[i].classList.add(all_buttons[i].classList[1];
   all_buttons[i].classList.add('btn-danger');
}
```

console.log stated "i" was not defined.  I then changed "let" to "var" in the line of code and now console.log says cannot read property of classList of undefined.

Comment: I suspect you misread the message. It didn't say that `i` was undefined, it said that `all_buttons[i]` was undefined.

Comment: How are you creating `all_buttons`? If it's from `document.getElementsByClassName()`, the list changes when you change the classes.

Comment: You are also missing closing `)` in your first 2 statements

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587769/classname-only-changing-every-other-class

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet with fixed syntax. I added inline comments for explanation.

```js
function buttonRed() { // function declaration need parenthesis

  for (let i=0; i < all_buttons.length; i++)  {
   all_buttons[i].classList.remove(all_buttons[i].classList[1]); // missing closing )
   all_buttons[i].classList.add(all_buttons[i].classList[1]); // missing closing )
   all_buttons[i].classList.add('btn-danger');
  }

} // missing ending bracket for function definition
```